# How to determine speed and angle of swipe in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to create an iOS app in Swift that involves getting the angle and the speed at which the user swipes the screen.

Is there a way to measure the angle and speed of a user's screen swipe and save the value as a Double/Float?

Thanks(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that a UISwipeGestureRecognizer gives you the information you're looking for, but you could use a UIPanGestureRecognizer and check velocity(in:) whenever it moves, which gives you a CGPoint representing the current speed in points/second on the x and y axes. Anything with a high enough speed can be considered a swipe, so then you'd just use those two values to get your angle.